# Different spawning on a radio beacon behaviors

Tags: battlefield-3

There are two different behaviors when you spawn on radio beacon: you either spawn right on it, or you parachute from above it's position.

What does that depend on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From personal experience and some research I can confirm you only spawn on the ground        (on the open air maps) when there is some form of terrain feature ABOVE your radio beacon.
If you put it in a building you spawn inside the building.
If you put it on a roof or anywhere with clear access to the sky you spawn above it in the air in your parachute.

some maps have a ceiling that is too low for parachuting in,these are the exception to the rule.

I've even found that some trees (not all of them though) will block an aerial spawn and make you spawn on the ground.

hope this helped : )